# jQuery: how to select the last N columns of each row in a table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table with 6 columns. I want to run a function on the last 3 columns of each row (excluding the header row). I have the following selector that is working:

```
$('table.listviewtable > tbody > tr:gt(0)').find('td:gt(2)')
    .each(function () { runMyFunction($(this)); });
```

Is there a way to do this all in one selector (ie, without the intermediate `find`)?

**Update:**

I've tried

```
$('table.listviewtable > tbody > tr:gt(0) td:gt(2)')
```

and

```
$('table.listviewtable > tbody > tr:gt(0) > td:gt(2)')
```

but they did not work. They returned the 4th, 5th, and 6th columns of the 2nd row and all columns of all subsequent rows.

Comment: `td:gt(2)` doesn't work because it excludes the first 3 TD elements from the entire set of TD elements, and not the first 3 TD elements from each row.

Comment: @Sime: yes, I figured that out. That's when I put in the intermediate find() to get the original version working. And since there is a big different between index and child, I restored part of the question title. For future reference, I want it to be clear that I wanted the columns of each row (children) and not the last columns of the last row in the table (index).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$('table.listviewtable td:nth-child(n+4)')
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/qJ3tP/1/

(I'm assuming you're using TH elements for the header cells.)

Comment: YES! That is it exactly. I could tell even before I tested it. I looked at nth-child, but all the examples showed multipliers of n. It never occurred to try addition. It must be the end of the day on Friday. Thanks!

Comment: @Rich The spec provides great examples: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: If the table uses `<TD>` elements for the header row use `$('table.listviewtable tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(n+4)')` http://jsfiddle.net/CeRvV/2/

Answer (score 6):

#### Rule

A generic rule to get the X last TD of a TR is:

```js
$('#tbl tr td:nth-last-child(-n+X)');
```

#### Example

```js
// Example for the last 3 paragraphs in some section:
$('#my_section p:nth-last-child(-n+3)');

// It's exactly the same as:
$('#my_section p:nth-last-child(3-n)');
```

#### Demo

```html
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
  td {
    border: solid 1px #999;
    padding: 2px;
  }
</style>

<!-- HTML -->
<p>Last 3 cells made gray using jQuery</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tr td:nth-last-child(-n+3)').css('background', '#CCC');
  });
</script>
```

#### Thanks

http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table.listviewtable > tbody > tr td:gt(2)')
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and most obvious selector, would be:

```
$('tr').each(
function(){
    $(this).find('td:gt(2)').css('background-color','#ffa');
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uUjJA/).

**Edited** because I'm an idiot, and overlooked the obvious flaw in the first suggestion. Incidentally, I'm assuming proper mark-up, using `th` for the heading rows. However you could amend the selector to:

```
 $('tbody tr')
```

To work around that, if you're not using `th` elements.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$('td:gt(2)', 'table.litviewtable')
```

of course if you use th in header.